# Is there a way to do lerna bootstrap to skip dependency installation?

Tags: javascript, monorepo, lerna

Based on Lerna documentation the bootstrap command will run 4 steps.

> 1. npm install all external dependencies of each package.
> 2. Symlink together all Lerna packages that are dependencies of each other.
> 3. npm run prepublish in all bootstrapped packages (unless --ignore-prepublish is passed).
> 4. npm run prepare in all bootstrapped packages.

Source: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/main/commands/bootstrap

In summary I want Lerna to skip step 1, so it would symlink and run the lifecycle events (`prepublish` and `prepare`).

Comment: I don't think this is possible without modifying the code. If you want to link the packages use `learna link`, `learna run prepublish`, and `lerna run prepare`?